# NSLayoutConstraint is set but view won't shrink

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

So I have a view in a XIB that looks like this.

BLAH png 9877

Where BLAH and 9877 are two UILabels separated by a png. Both BLAH and 9877 are dynamic text.
I use this XIB in other storyboards.

I have set the following for constraints using storyboard (i.e. not code).
`BLAH<-png<-9877` (where <- means nearist neighbor is 3px).  This is working well.

In my Storyboard view, where I use the UIView of the XIB, I set via constraints the following.

```
Height=40 and Width <= 150.
```

The problem is when the XIB shows this, it looks correct.

```
[BLAH png 9877]
```

But when the text in the XIB is this, it wont resize.

```
[B png 9      ]
```

I want the it to resize and look like this.

```
[B png 9]
```

I thought by setting width to <= it would resize, but it doesn't. Do I need to tell it to resize? I don't have any other constraints on it.

UPDATE:
I set the content hugging priority on the view, in my storyboard, that holds the XIB and it is now shrinking the view, but only about 3 pixels.

UPDATE 2:
I fixed the XIB not shrinking problem by throwin all of the XIB's inter subviews in side another view. So it looks like this now.

```
View
  View
    All UILABELS AND PNGS
```

BUT Now the view in my storyboard that is of type MYXIB (i.e. the xib above), will not shrink. I have its width set to <= 143px, 10px = from left side and 5px from right nearest neighbor. But it always stays at 143px width?

Comment: I think it is because the right hand side UILabel has fixed width. You would need to make the width dynamic based on the content.

Comment: No I checked that already and their is no constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you omitted some constraints in your description, it appears that you don't have any constraints from the right of the second label to the container that holds everything - a trailing constraint. In addition, make sure you add a constraint from the first label to the left - a leading constraint.